# Dynamic content of User Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to create some user control with some common data (header and footer) and repeater inside.

I want to bind Repeater in different ways depending on the Page being used.

I.e.

```
<div>Header Title</div>
<div>
    <asp:Repeater>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <!--   content that can be different on different pages    !-->

        </Itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<div>Footer Title</div>
```

The problem that I'm using some external jquery Lib for the current Repeater and I want to have only one box (UserControl) with the ready functionality, but change content on different ways.

What is the best way to Bind this repeater ?

I was thinking about Dynamic Binding in the Code behind, but probably there is some ASP.Net tempplate functionality (like ContentPlaceHolder) can be used.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What is your desired solution? javascript on the front end, or asp:Repeater in code behind?

Comment: asp:Repeater in code behind

Comment: Use the `Request` object to find out which Page is implementing your User Control, then change the binding accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer